# Replicating Exponentiation function in Power Query

Tags: excel, formula, powerquery

Trying to replicate : =((1+LP)/((1+MA)^(1/12)))-1)

Where LP Is -0.028879249 & MA is 0.0035 (As a working example). The output from the above Excel formula would be: -2.92%

The issue I am having is I am not sure if the formula I am using in Power query would react the same as the "^" exponent in Excel:

**Number.Power((1+[LP_Value])/(1+[MA_Value]),(1/12)) as nullable number**

I am also unable to add in the -1 required at the end as it comes up with syntax issues.

If anyone could shed some light for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent formula in PQ is:

```
= ((1+[LP_Value])/Number.Power(1+[MA_Value],1/12))-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue i was having was that Excel was employing BODMAS rules whereas the formula above was not accounting for that:

(Value.Divide((1+[LP_Value]),Number.Power(1+[MA_Value],(1/12)))-1)

For anyone who might find this interesting.

Comment: Check parentheses in your formulas. Formulas in Excel =((1+-0.028879249)/((1+0.0035)^(1/12)))-1
and in PQ = ((1+-0.028879249)/Number.Power(1+0.0035,1/12))-1
should give same result: -0,0291619568714618

Comment: Thanks for your help - both seem to return the same results, yours is more streamlined however :)